# For multiple DataGrids in a ScrollViewer, how do I keep the header of the currently visible grid at the top of the window?

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, datagrid

I'm not so great at describing things, so sorry in advance.
Basically, I have an unknown number of data grids, each bound to a different source, inside one big ScrollViewer so I can scroll through them all.
I'd like a way to keep the header of the grid the user is scrolling through visible, at the top, whilst it's still visible.
If the user completely scrolls past that grid to another grid, now that grids header need to be stickied at the top, and so on.

So here's most of the xaml:

```xml
<Window ......>
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataGrid x:Key="ItemDataGrid"
                      x:Shared="False"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                      AutoGeneratedColumns="Dg_items_AutoGeneratedColumns"
                      AutoGeneratingColumn="Dg_items_AutoGeneratingColumn"
                      CanUserAddRows="False"
                      CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                      CellEditEnding="Dg_items_CellEditEnding"
                      EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                      GotFocus="Dg_items_GotFocus"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                      SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader"
                      Sorting="Dg_items_Sorting"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
                                     Handler="Dg_items_cell_MouseClick"/>
                        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick"
                                     Handler="Dg_items_cell_MouseClick"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.Resources>
            </DataGrid>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

<!-- I'm cutting out the first row, it's mostly a bar with buttons and not important. -->
<!-- This is the row with the DataGrids: -->

        <ScrollViewer Name="scroll_viewer"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      Grid.Column="0"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
                      PreviewMouseWheel="ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel">
            <Grid Name="grid"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

That `<Grid Name="grid"/>` in there is what I add my generated DataGrids to with this:

```cs
        public DataGrid AddDataGrid<T>(IEnumerable<T> itemSource) {
            var control = new ContentControl {Content = Resources["ItemDataGrid"]};
            grid.AddControl(control);
            var dataGrid = ((DataGrid) control.Content);
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = itemSource is ObservableCollection<T> ? itemSource : new ObservableCollection<T>(itemSource);
            return dataGrid;
        }
```

(I don't know if this is the best way to do what I've done, but it works. Also, Labels will generally be added in there too, one fore each DataGrid; not so important, but they just mingle in the vertical list of grids.)

Everything's done dynamic in code, there's no way to know what columns will be present at compile time. 
This also includes the DataGrids themselves, and is why we have 'AutoGeneratingColumn'.

I know it's me doing this in a ScrollViewer that's preventing the headers from sticking, but I need a way to show an indefinite number of DataGrids vertically and know of no better solution.

So... How do I keep the headers visible for the currently visible DataGrid in the ScrollViewer?

Answer (score 0):

I see one problem with implementation of this task using a simple ScrollViewer control. The problem occurs because the ScrollViewer has infinit space inside. It will force your grids to add all their content inside instead of using the RowVirtualization. I suggest you check on your real data how critical this problem will be for you. 
If you see that your grids are rather small and there are no performance issues, then you can use RenderTransform to move headers based on the current ScrollViewer postion. 
If you see the performance issue, then it may be necessary to use a standalone scrollbar control to scroll grids one by one and dynamically calculate their height. E.g. by default display only the first grid and set height of other to 0, and use this scrollbar only to scroll its content. When you scroll to its end, you will need to reduce the height of the first grid an increase the size of the second grid to bring it into the view. Then start to scroll the second grid when it fill all awailable space, and so on. 
Looks like not a trivial task with a big number of possible difficulties.